# Many python's module error when i try to run nosetests

Tags: python, macos, unit-testing, numpy, nosetests

Why when i run `nosetests` i will stuck in several errors about python's module for example:

```
...
    output = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(deg)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'leggauss'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.954s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I'm not sure is it about dependency problem or i miss some setup step before i run `nosetests`.

But anyway for sure that i have no problem when i run my main program, it work well. but for my test file it stuck in error.

Addtional: In actually, for numpy there are 3 lines of calling numpy before `output = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(deg)` line

```
  8 A = np.zeros(shape=(deg, deg), dtype=np.complex)
  9 R = np.zeros(shape=(deg), dtype=np.complex)
 10 J = np.zeros(shape=(deg))
 11 output = np.polynomial.legendre.leggauss(deg)
```

but for line 8, 9, 10 no any errors but error was occured on line 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, everything fine. I just forgot to export path.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/opt/local/lib/python2.7
```

put it on ~/.profile